# Fire event on word wrap, multiline TextBox (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have written a method for limiting the number of lines allowed to write in a multiline textbox (since this is not a property provided by Microsoft). The method works in all cases, except when a wordwrap event occurs (when typing a single char, or when pasting text from clipboard). The code I hace right now:

```
    protected void limitLineNumbers(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e, UInt16 numberOfLines)
    {
        int[] specialChars = { 1, 3, 8, 22, 24, 26 }; // ctrl+a, ctrl+c, backspace, ctrl+v, ctrl+x, ctrl+z
        bool found = false;
        string lastPressedChar = "";
        TextBox temp = (TextBox)sender;

        foreach (int i in specialChars)
        {
            if (i == (int)e.KeyChar)
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found)
            lastPressedChar = e.KeyChar.ToString(); // Only add if there is a "real" char

        int currentLine = temp.GetLineFromCharIndex(temp.SelectionStart) + 1;
        int totalNumberOfLines = temp.GetLineFromCharIndex(temp.TextLength) + 1;

        if ((int)e.KeyChar == 1)
            temp.SelectAll();

        // Paste text from clipboard (ctrl+v)
        else if ((int)e.KeyChar == 22)
        {
            string clipboardData = Clipboard.GetText();
            int lineCountCopiedText = 0;
            foreach (char c in clipboardData)
            {
                if (c.Equals("\n"))
                    ++lineCountCopiedText;
            }
            if ((currentLine > numberOfLines || (totalNumberOfLines + lineCountCopiedText) > numberOfLines))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
        // Carrige return (enter)
        else if ((int)e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            if ((currentLine + 1) > numberOfLines || (totalNumberOfLines + 1) > numberOfLines)
                e.Handled = true;
        }

        // Disallow
        else if ((currentLine > numberOfLines) || (totalNumberOfLines > numberOfLines))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

So, do you guys have some ideas how I can make this method more complete? The best solution would be to catch the wordwrap event, but as far as I can understand, this can't be done? The other solution would be to delete the line(s) of text, if it exceeds the maximum allowed.

Or is it possible a better solution than the one I came up with? Appreciate your input.

Comment: Thinking out aloud here, so sorry if it's not what you want. As I assume you know the font size, you can reliably count (with your own eyes) how many letters would fit in your textbox. This can then be used to detect when a line has wrapped? i.e. if the line is longer than 32 chars, then the additional chars appear on a second line?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that each char has a different dimension. For instance, 'W' is much wider than 'i'. I have a different method that checks for this on a single line textbox. In addition, I really want to use the wordwrap provided by Microsoft.

Comment: I came across this whilst looking around that may be a different way of looking at it. http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_detect_wordwrap.html it's in VB but won't take much to convert to C#.

Comment: Maybe you can use MeasureString to determine how much lines are occupied? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0ae0hxt

Comment: @Gavin This looks promising. However, I have zero experience with VB. Do you know how to omit the event?

Comment: There isn't an event, or at least not that I am aware of. You would need to manually implement it.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I use MeasureString to limit chars typed on a single-line textbox. However, the same problem will happen here, since the wordwrap event fires first.

Comment: @Gavin Hm, then I guess the problem still exists. I need to cancel the wordwrap from ever occuring.